# I cannot edit the information with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I've modified thousands of times my Controller and my Model which are in charge of editing the information of the DB, but I don't know what is wrong. I've modified the names putting it accordingly to the DB's column names but nothing seems to work. The rest of the elements of the CRUD are working but this is the only one that it's not.

Here I include the controller **controller/itemCRUD/edit**

```php
    public function update($id)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fechaalta', 'Fechaalta');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre', 'Nombre');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('apellidos', 'Apellidos');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nif', 'Nif');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('direccion', 'Direccion');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('localidad', 'Localidad');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cp', 'Cp');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('provincia', 'Provincia');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comunidad', 'Comunidad');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefono', 'Telefono');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('movil', 'Movil');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lugarnacimiento', 'Lugarnacimiento');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fechanacimiento', 'Fechanacimiento');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cuentabancaria', 'Cuentabancaria');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefonotrabajo', 'Telefonotrabajo');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lugartrabajo', 'Lugartrabajo');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('direcciontrabajo', 'Direcciontrabajo');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('localidadtrabajo', 'Localidadtrabajo');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('colegiado', 'Colegiado');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ejerciente', 'Ejerciente');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('titulacion', 'Titulacion');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('otrostitulos', 'Otrostitulos');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('especialidad', 'Especialidad');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ambitotrabajo', 'Ambitotrabajo');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sector', 'Sector');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('solicitahabilitacion', 'Solicitahabilitacion');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('diplomaturalogopedia', 'Diplomaturalogopedia');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('altabolsatrabajo', 'altabolsatrabajo');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('traslado', 'Traslado');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('colegioorigen', 'Colegioorigen');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('numcolegiado', 'Numcolegiado');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('observaciones', 'Observaciones');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('publicidad', 'Publicidad');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('activo', 'Activo');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());
            redirect(base_url('itemCRUD/edit/' . $id));
        } else {
            $this->itemCRUD->update_item($id);
            redirect(base_url('itemCRUD'));
        }
    }
```

And here is the model **models/itemCRUDmodel/update_item**

```php
    public function update_item($id)
    {
        $data = array(
            'Fechaalta' => $this->input->post('fechaalta'),
            'Nombre' => $this->input->post('nombre'),
            'Apellidos' => $this->input->post('apellidos'),
            'NIF' => $this->input->post('nif'),
            'Direccion' => $this->input->post('direccion'),
            'Localidad' => $this->input->post('localidad'),
            'CP' => $this->input->post('cp'),
            'Provincia' => $this->input->post('provincia'),
            'Comunidad' => $this->input->post('comunidad'),
            'Telefono' => $this->input->post('telefono'),
            'Movil' => $this->input->post('movil'),
            'Email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'Lugarnacimiento' => $this->input->post('lugarnacimiento'),
            'Fechanacimiento' => $this->input->post('fechanacimiento'),
            'Cuentabancaria' => $this->input->post('cuentabancaria'),
            'Telefonotrabajo' => $this->input->post('telefonotrabajo'),
            'Lugartrabajo' => $this->input->post('lugartrabajo'),
            'Direcciontrabajo' => $this->input->post('direcciontrabajo'),
            'Localidadtrabajo' => $this->input->post('localidadtrabajo'),
            'Colegiado' => $this->input->post('colegiado'),
            'Ejerciente' => $this->input->post('ejerciente'),
            'Titulacion' => $this->input->post('titulacion'),
            'Otrostitulos' => $this->input->post('otrostitulos'),
            'Especialidad' => $this->input->post('especialidad'),
            'Ambitotrabajo' => $this->input->post('ambitotrabajo'),
            'Sector' => $this->input->post('sector'),
            'Solicitahabilitacion' => $this->input->post('solicitahabilitacion'),
            'Diplomaturalogopedia' => $this->input->post('diplomaturalogopedia'),
            'Altabolsatrabajo' => $this->input->post('altabolsatrabajo'),
            'Trasladado' => $this->input->post('traslado'),
            'Colegiorigen' => $this->input->post('colegiorigen'),
            'Numcolegiado' => $this->input->post('numcolegiado'),
            'Observaciones' => $this->input->post('observaciones'),
            'Publicidad' => $this->input->post('publicidad'),
            'Activo' => $this->input->post('activo'),
        );

        if ($id == 0) {
            return $this->db->insert('colegiados', $data);
        } else {
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            return $this->db->update('colegiados', $data);
        }
    }
```

And here is part of the view **views/itemCRUD/edit**

```php
    <section class="junta app" style="margin-top: 2.1em; margin-bottom: -5.1em; height: 2700;">

    <?php $this->load->view('templates/menu_admin'); ?>

    <div class="container" style="width: 70%; padding:0; margin-right:2em; margin-top: -185em;">
        <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

        <?php echo form_open('itemCRUD/update/'.$item->Id); ?>
            <div class="row">

            <?php
            if ($this->session->flashdata('errors')){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
                echo $this->session->flashdata('errors');
                echo "</div>";
            }


            ?>

            <h3 style="color: #004987; text-transform: uppercase; font-size:3em">Editar Colegiado</h3>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Fecha Alta:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="fechaalta" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->FechaAlta; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Nombre:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Nombre; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Apellidos:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Apellidos; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Nif:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="nif" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->NIF; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Dirección:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Direccion; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Localidad:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="localidad" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Localidad; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Código Postal:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="cp" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->CP; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Provincia:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="provincia" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Provincia; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Comunidad:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="comunidad" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Comunidad; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Teléfono:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="telefono" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Telefono; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Móvil:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="movil" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Movil; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Email:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Email; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Lugar de Nacimiento:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="lugarnacimiento" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->LugarNacimiento; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Fecha de Nacimiento:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="fechanacimiento" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->FechaNacimiento; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Cuenta Bancaria:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="cuentabancaria" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->CuentaBancaria; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Teléfono de trabajo:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="telefonotrabajo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->TelefonoTrabajo; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Lugar de Trabajo:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="lugartrabajo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->LugarTrabajo; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Dirección de Trabajo:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="direcciontrabajo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->DireccionTrabajo; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Localidad de Trabajo:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="localidadtrabajo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->LocalidadTrabajo; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Nº de Colegiado:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="colegiado" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Colegiado; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Ejerciente:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="ejerciente" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Ejerciente; ?>">
                </div>
            </div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Especialidad:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="especialidad" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Especialidad; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Ámbito de Trabajo:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="ambitotrabajo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->AmbitoTrabajo; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Sector de Trabajo:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="sector" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Sector; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Solicita Habilitación:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="solicitahabilitacion" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->SolicitaHabilitacion; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Diplomado en Logopedia:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="diplomaturalogopedia" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->DiplomaturaLogopedia; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Titulación:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="titulacion" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Titulacion; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Otras Titulaciones:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="otrostitulos" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->OtrosTitulos; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Bolsa de Trabajo:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="altabolsatrabajo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->AltaBolsaTrabajo; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Traslado:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="traslado" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Trasladado; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Colegio de Origen:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="colegioorigen" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->ColegioOrigen; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Nº Colegiado de Origen:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="numcolegiado" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->NumColegiado; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Observaciones:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="observaciones" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Observaciones; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Publicidad:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="publicidad" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Publicidad; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Colegiado Actualmente:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="activo" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $item->Activo; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-acceso text-uppercase">Modificar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

If you see anything that I'm not, please, please, please, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You need to do some debugging to determine where things go wrong because you have everything there from html to code that interacts with the database. For example,if the values are passed from the client to the php code correctly, then you can remove the client side code from the question, etc. Unless there is some kind of a very obvious syntax os logical error, it is very difficult to spot an error with a large codebase just on the vague statement of "it does not work"!

Comment: What's the point of all those `set_rules()` calls when you're not actually passing in any rules? Also, what does "not working" mean here? Wrong data? White page? Error messages? Have you checked the error log?

Comment: The thing is that I'm not receiving any errors. The DB is not being updated and the information is not being modified. I truly believe that the problem is related with the form.

Comment: @M.Eriksson this is how codeigniter works. I think. All the documentation says that. If you have any better suggestion, please, let me know.

Comment: If you check [the documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-validation-rules), all examples do pass the validation rules as well (third argument), which you aren't doing. If you want to validate the form, then you need to tell CI _how_ it should validate the different inputs.

Comment: Regarding your issue, what debugging have you done? Have you checked what data you get form the form?

Comment: @M.Eriksson thank you so much for the information. I thought that it was necessary to use set_rules all the time. My bad. I'm trying to apply one for Codeigniter but I'm having some errors and it's not working. Any suggestion about that?

Comment: Help with what? Just saying _"I'm having some errors and it's not working"_ tells me nothing. If you're asking about form validation, please check the manual.

Comment: I thought that I've explained the problem in the question: I'm trying to update the information in the DB but nothing happens. If I would have more information I'll include it. Of course. That's all that I have. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Not sure your route looks like but maybe this is your problem:

Your controller: controller/itemCRUD/**edit**

But your form route is: `<?php echo form_open('itemCRUD/update/' . $item->Id); ?>` with **update**

Check if you use the right route.

Comment: Thank you @Canh for the suggestion but it's not working either. I'll try to reduce the number of items in the form and add one at a time till I find out what's going wrong. Thanks!